# Does it make sense to compare coefficient of variance between samples with different sample size?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have two samples with different sample sizes. The difference is quite large: one has sample size of 10 and one has sample size of 200. Two samples are same type of data but are collected from two places (For example, one from California and one from New York). Due to external limitation, I can only collect 10 data points for the first sample. I calculate the coefficient of variance for these two samples and attempt to compare the degree of variation of these two samples based on coefficient of variance.I wonder does it make sense to compare coefficient of variance between samples with different sample size? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question for the Statistics stack, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  I would recommend applying the [$F$-test for equality of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances) to your two samples.  There can be problems with sensitivity to non-normality of the underlying process.  If visually inspecting your data shows noticeable non-normality, I would recommend using a different test, e.g. [Levene's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levene%27s_test), as suggested at the $F$-test link above.

I suspect the respondents at Cross Validated will have a more nuanced view of non-normality and may provide a variety of recommended alternative tests.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I wonder if I increase the number of samples, like having 50 samples instead of 2 samples. If I want to rank the variances, is F-test or Levene's test still the best way to approach?

Comment: I'm not sure that *ranking* variances is meaningful.  The test is to determine whether two (numerically different) variances are likely different because of a difference in the process that produced them or are different due to random variations in your samples.  Just because $s_1 < s_2$ does not mean that they are justifiably unequal.  You want to compare process variances, but you only have sample variances, so you only have a very fuzzy notion of the process variances.  That fuzziness means that many apparently different pairs are not justifiably different (or ordered in either order).